# Stuck while Generating Token in App Script using ScriptApp.getIdentityToken() gives error as Null Token in Google Sheet

Tags: google-sheets, google-apps-script, google-cloud-functions

`Hello everyone,

We are trying to create a custom function in Google Sheets that will trigger a Cloud Function using Google App Script

Google Sheet -> custom function -> Google App Script -> Cloud Function

The Cloud Function used is HTTP Cloud Function and will be triggered using

```
UrlFetchApp.fetch()
```

As cloud function requires Identity token, we have generated Identity token using “ScriptApp.getIdentityToken()” in App script.
We want to invoke the cloud function as a user who is logged in to the google sheet. If the user has access to invoke cloud function the user should be able to invoke and get data from Cloud function else must get an error.

We have set the following scopes (as read by many articles and posts on stackoverflow)

Manifest file: appsscript.json

```
{
  "timeZone": "Asia/Kolkata",
  "dependencies": {
  },
  "exceptionLogging" : "STACKDRIVER",
  "runtimeVersion" : "V8",
  "oauthScopes" : [
    "openid" ,
    "https://www.googleapis.com/auth/spreadsheets",
    "https://www.googleapis.com/auth/script.external_request",
    "https://www.googleapis.com/auth/cloud-platform",
    "https://www.googleapis.com/auth/spreadsheets.currentonly"
  ]
}
```

We have changed the project of App Script to the project where our cloud function resides.

We have given the Google Sheet user permission to invoke cloud function. In Fact we have given him Cloud Function Admin role (for sake of making it work!)

The Problem:
Identity Token is not able to be created when the user executes the custom function from Google Sheet. We tried logging and printed the token.

```
token = ScriptApp.getIdentityToken();
Logger.log(token);


Which gives the output:

[error]: Cloud Logs
         --------------------------------------------------- 
             Feb 1, 2024, 4:46:17 PM   Info    Token null
```

Because of which cloud function invocation fails with following error

```
Exception: Request failed for https://asia-south1-test-project.cloudfunctions.net returned code 401. Truncated server response: 
<html><head>
<meta http-equiv="content-type" content="text/html;charset=utf-8">
<title>401 Unauthorized</title>
</head>
<body text=#000000 bgcolor... (use muteHttpExceptions option to examine full response)
    at callCloudFunction(Code:39:30)
```

But if I Run the same function from App Script directly
It prints Identity Token (JWT) of OAuth 2.0 Client ID created for the App Script project in GCP Project (that was created along with the Oauth Consent screen). And executes the cloud function as expected.

Things Tried:
Created a separate function to get Identity Token; cached that token and the used it in main function
Used service account (This was our last resort, as we do not want to call Cloud Function using service account)

We have been stuck on this problem; it will do a world of good if you could help us! Thanks in advance.`

Answer (score 0):

Custom functions do not ask a user for permissions and do not use previously authorized scopes ([documentation](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/sheets/functions#using_services)). Due to that they cannot use some of the Google Apps Script services.

The documentation suggests using a custom function via a custom menu, i.e. context that requires user's authorization.